# SWT/JFace: Disable focus of toolbar item in scrolled form

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an instance of a ScrolledForm in a form editor page and when I add a toolbar item to this form it always gets the focus (a blue background):

```
...
import org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormPage;
...

class ModelPage extends FormPage {

  ...

  @Override
  protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm mform) {
      Action action = …
      ScrolledForm form = mform.getForm();
      IToolBarManager toolbar = form.getToolBarManager();
      toolbar.add(action);
      toolbar.update(true);
      ...
  }

  @Override
  public void setFocus() {
      // this does not work
      someText.setFocus();
  }
}
```

Is there an easy method for removing the focus from this item? I could do this via setting the focus to other controls in listeners but this is not very nice (the item seems to get the focus always when the editor page is activated). I cannot set the style flag `SWT.NO_FOCUS` as the toolbar is already created by the form, right?

Thanks for help

Comment: If you have a `IFormPart` (for example `SectionPart`) overriding the `setFocus` method to set the focus on one of your part controls should work.

Comment: @greg-449 Many thanks for the comment. It is a 3.x application running on the 4.4 platform using the compatibility layer. Maybe it is related to that. I tried to overwrite the setFocus method of the FormPage but this has no effect.

Comment: Where are you running this code?